# SilverStripe FullTextSearch change template renderWith

Tags: php, full-text-search, silverstripe

I can't seem to change the templates that the results function uses. I've taken the results function and modified the template but it's rendering with Page.ss instead of MyCustomResultTemplate.ss

```
public function results($data, $form, $request)
{
    // [...]

    $templates = array(
        'MyCustomResultTemplate',
        'Page'
    );

    return $this->owner->customise($data)->renderWith($templates);
}
```

MyCustomResultTemplate.ss exists in the correct templates folder and looks identical the the default Page_results.ss file yet still no luck.

Am I missing some route setting or something here?

Comment: Are you running this code in an Extension for a controller? Did you flush? What is the path to your MyCustomResultTemplate.ss ?

Comment: No just in a standard controller, yes to the flush, and have put the customer template in both templates and templates/Layout both have the same result.

Comment: $this->owner is for Extensions, try `return $this->customise($data)->renderWith($templates);` instead.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but that code is from another controller written by Silverstripe so was also a tad confused on that. Will try your recommendation in the morning, cheers